# Possible conjugations on certain grammar patterns

Tags: grammar, verbs, conjugations

On *"A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar"*, when a grammar pattern works with the informal form of a verb, they only talk about the positive present tense and the positive past tense. (At least until page 131, which is where I'm currently in). I think it's just the way this book works, but I'm not absolutely sure.

For example:

Could...

> 雪子さんとはデートしただけです。

...be...

> 雪子さんとはデートできないだけです。

?

---

Or could...

> あの人はよく勉強するだけではなくよく遊びます。

...be...

> あの人はあまり勉強しないだけではなくあまり遊びません。

?

---

By the way, when we use informal adjectives, could I write...

> この家は大きくないだけです。

...or can't I use the negative form?

---

The same question for な-adjectives. Can I say:

> このお菓子は色がきれいじゃないだけです。

?

---

Basically, my question is: whenever I see *"Vinf"* (informal verb) or *"Adj (i) inf"* (informal い-adjective) on this book, can I assume it's **every** informal form?

Answer (score 1):

ない behaves like an i-adjective. You may end up with some strange sentences (雪子さんとはデートできないだけです, but you can turn water into wine)
but grammatically you can do what you are suggesting.